# A msg pops up: 'Error, could not load media' when trying to crop a jpg picked from Gallery on an Android AVD API Level 31

Tags: android, gallery, crop, android-virtual-device, android-gallery

In my Android app, I just select a JPG from the Gallery through Intent.ACTION_PICK, then pass its URI to CROP intent.
But, on an AVD(API Level 31), I got a pop-up message: 'Error, could not load media', then the crop feature failed to start.

In fact, that JPG file locates on Stoareg\Pictures folder. And in Files app, I found its original URI is 'content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A74'.

After calling Intent.ACTION_PICK, I got its URI.
mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

In LogCat, I Logger.D() the URI mImageCaptureUri. It's as below.
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F76/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/296819256

**Q1**: Why did this URI change? It seems to have a strange prefix.

**Q2**: Is this weird URI causing the startup cropping to fail?

**Q3**: What's even more surprising is, this app works well on an AVD of API Level 33, and the startup cropping function is completely normal.

So now, I'm curious to know, **what's going on here?**

Comment: Both are normal uries for a file. They are only from different file/content providers or authorities. You could easily build yet another uri using FileProvider for this file. Or your own provider.

Comment: Thank you. But why failed to load source image?

Comment: For Q3, AVD-API Level 31 failed while AVD - API Level 33 worked fine. A difference between these 2 AVD is, the AVD-API Level 31 is system image for Google APIs(not logged in Google account) while the AVD-API Level 33 is system image for Google Play(logged in Google account). Does it have anything to do with this?

Comment: Just use the uries to load the images in an imageview or something like that. Or open an inputstream and read from the stream. If that goes without problems you know that both providers deliver the file. Whatever you do letting crop the files we dont know. We dont know which apps are involved. They will be different for every device. Try other apps to crop the stuff

Comment: Thank you @blackapps . On the AVD, the only cropping app is Google Photo.

Comment: Did it require to request some runtime permission on API Level 31 AVD which only supports Google APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. At last, I found that this issue resulted from the Intent.ACTION_PICK on API Level 31 AVD while it works fine on any other API Level AVDs.
I changed to use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, and now it works fine on all API Level AVDs. Share with you all. Thanks again.